# How to search objects to see if they contain a specific value?

Tags: php, drupal, search, object

I have various objects that look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 18
        [vid] => 1
        [name] => test
        [description] => 
        [format] => 
        [weight] => 0
        [depth] => 0
        [parents] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 21
        [vid] => 1
        [name] => tag
        [description] => 
        [format] => 
        [weight] => 0
        [depth] => 0
        [parents] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )
)
```

Basically I need to find out weather a [name] value exists in these objects, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: One of the most important skills a developer can have is the ability to _Google_.

Comment: What do you mean exists? Does it just have to be defined? Does it have to have a value? Not empty?

Comment: Basically the value of property. For example if [name] contains 'test'   perform a particular operation.

Comment: You only need to know _whether_ any object has the name 'test', or you need to find the one and only object that has the name 'test', or you need to find _all_ objects with the name 'test'? You could build a dictionary of all the names, or a map from names to objects, or to lists of objects, if they're not unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if the `name` property exists in an object:

```
if(isset($obj->name)) {
    // It exists!
}
```

So, if you want to find those objects that had `$name` properties:

```
$result = array_filter($myArray, function($x) {
    return isset($x->name);
}); // Assuming PHP 5.3 or higher
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's the actual value I need. I have tried various things such as counting the array items and then using a for loop to check weather each name property of each object equals my value. This I think is working at the moment but if there are a lot of objects, could this get quite slow?

Comment: @Robert: That would depend on how many objects you have, but there's really no faster way to search through an unsorted list.

Comment: Is it possible to check multiple properties at a time, instead of using isset() for every property ?

Comment: @dskanth: You can pass multiple variables to `isset`, and it’s the same of `and`ing them all together.